# GLKView with stencil buffer's glDrawElements results in black screen

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit, glkview

I have an iOS app that uses GLKViewController and I set up the render buffer as follows:

inside
`@interface RootViewController : GLKViewController<UIKeyInput>`

```
- viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    GLKView* view = (GLKView*)self.view;
    view.context = _context;
    view.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
    view.drawableStencilFormat = GLKViewDrawableStencilFormat8;
    view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisampleNone;
    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
}
```

However, when I call draw later:

`glDrawElements(getGlPrimitiveType(ePrimType), numIndis, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, startIndis);`

It results in black screen and upon `Capture GPU Frame`, this error shows up:

`Your app rendered with STENCIL_TEST enabled into a framebuffer without an attached stencil buffer.`

Is there anything that I missed?

I remembered having the same problem before due to depth testing, and I fix it with the `view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;` on `viewDidLoad` I am not sure about stencil testing, Apple's documentation is either very minimal or very general with theories all around (i.e: pretty much useless).

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit,

I've lost the original FBO-ID already setup by GLKView when I do render to texture:

```
uint m_nFboId;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_nFboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_nFboId);
```

then, when I try to reset back to the original FBO-ID:

```
GLint defaultFBO;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &defaultFBO);
```

here, the `defaultFBO` is the value of `m_nFboId` generated before.. So the solution is to either back it up before the operation, or call back `[GLKView bindDrawable];`